# Migrating JavaScript to TypeScript: how to deal with Object.defineProperties used on `this`?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to port some JavaScript code to TypeScript.

One of the classes looks like this ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoa1jwHYQBcAnAV2APiIAoBKFDLLAeQCMArAU3IDoATDgGYBLXBwAKReAAcORAkI4QqBABZCIAGnqZGWMAC5tu3QDcwIEh0MByMNY0NjAXwfpHulobQ7j0MxatoaxZ7d0YXDDCsXC8oxgB3IiECMBYQQOJLV18sf0tDAAZs52KsJxoAbkifaEgIWQIEeABBKSFlNQhKxydqrCJFDgJaI0ZVdW4waABeILsqmvGIbhYZoJCF3SXuXDWCzehe9COMEQJZATBgDjhEVqFRg2hCJNwAc2LPZ%20IRD8cY6C4EgAWxYslcJ3QAhIuHIQjwtSgDSa9yoIikJAIhjAuAAnjRsUi5DB0ZjoOpbi02qMAPQ08m4c6M%20G4cwgXHQS4Aaw4GCcQA)):

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      a: {
        value: 'a',
      },

      b: {
        value: 'b',
      },

      n: {
        writable: true,
        value: 0,
      },
    });

    assertFooApi(this);
  }

  reset() {
    this.a = 'a';
    this.b = 'b';
    this.n = 0;
  }
}

interface FooApi {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  n: number,
}

function assertFooApi(input: any): asserts input is FooApi {
  // intentionally fake
}
```

This `reset` function errors because [`Object.defineProperties` doesn't affect the type signature in typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42919).

I did not write the original JavaScript code nor do I fully understand it. I'm looking for a way to define `this`'s type without modifying any behavior. The less changes I make to its existing implementation, the better. Eventually, I'll write automated tests around it so I *can* change its implementation, but as a step 1, I think porting it to typescript is the best bang for my buck.

[This comment provides two workarounds](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42919#issuecomment-1037382274) to the problem. I think they would work if I didn't need the workaround to apply to `this`. But as you can see (in the playground link above), using an assert function on `this` doesn't modify its internal type.

If a class defines properties on `this` with `Object.defineProperties`, how do I use those properties in other internal functions without compilation errors?

Comment: Since you're implementing a constructor and not defining properties after the fact why not use `readonly` and implement getter only props?

Comment: This example is a little _too_ contrived. What are you doing with those properties? Why is `reset()` writing to a readonly property? I suspect the best answer here is not use `Object.defineProperties` at all, and how to do that depends on why this was being used in the first place.

Comment: @pilchard `Foo` is a simple example of a complex, larger class I don't fully understand. Long term, I want to change its behavior, but first, I need to set up some feedback loops to inform me of when a modification has broken it (hence porting it to TS).

Comment: @AlexWayne I tried to update my question with an answer to that question

Comment: or use modern [private class features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields). [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wO2lRW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to define this's type without modifying any behavior

This is *exactly* what the `declare` keyword does. It creates type information but never emits any code.

It's rarely used in production code because it's so easy to make it lie to you about what type something really is. But, for cases like this you can add the properties with `declare` which tells the type system to expect them to be there.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Just be careful! If you change the code in `defineProperties` to create different properties, typescript can't pair this up and raise type errors. This may lead to runtime crashes. This is not a *proper* solution. But when porting untyped code to typed code incrementally, sometimes this unsafety is an improvement.

```
class Foo {

  declare readonly a: string
  declare readonly b: string
  declare n: number

  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      a: {
        value: 'a',
      },

      b: {
        value: 'b',
      },

      n: {
        writable: true,
        value: 0,
      },
    });
  }

  reset() {
    // changed these because they would be readonly
    console.log(this.a); // fine
    console.log(this.b); // fine

    this.n = 0; // fine
  }
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoD1oBMCmoYATntCWDvAHYgCe0YAXNBAC5ECWVA5lrgeBJk8FanWgAjZm048++QkKrMqAVwC2EvEQx9g1GauCt4RABQBKFH2wB5CQCsCrAHT4AZlzwAFIvAAO2qwceBBmrAAWHBAANNbo2IkMzGgJSYkAbmAgqnjMAORg+TE2iQC+JZhpSVLx6ZnZuQUSxaXYFbrVicp19dAA7pysYBIgedDsuZV90Fk54wAM0+kdXWUWANx8ZZ3YJBB4rJa92AD0p9DAEWA8eDgTEaGkWsBgqgcPePT98Kog91phKIaLRSvoqBB4GMXCB4NxwlEIC4wJtoOdoJ4qHgwQYoXgYXCEdEXBJUejMdiqklIsSqNAALzQBYbNEXCnbDBlIA)

Comment: I didn't know you could use the declared keyword *inside* a class. I actually tried to `declare class Foo` at the top level in an attempt to do that, but naturally it errored because that name was already used. Thank you!

Comment: good you added the caveat because if the OP is looking for type safety by moving to TS then this isn't it

Comment: @pilchard Technically, this is adding type safety relative to where it was; this class is imported and used in other files.

Comment: Definitely a step in the right direction, and the appropriate answer, just wanted to reiterate for the OP

Answer (score 2):

To convert this code to TS without changing its behaviour,

1. `declare` class fields (`declare`d fields compile to nothing)
2. Add `readonly` for non-writable fields
3. `implement` your interface to make sure it's properly implemented

```typescript
class Foo implements FooApi {
  declare readonly a: 'a' // non-writable so readonly literal
  declare readonly b: 'b' // non-writable so readonly literal
  declare n: number // writable
  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      a: { value: 'a', },
      b: { value: 'b', },
      n: {
        writable: true,
        value: 0,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Remember, that constructor's return value *type* doesn't affect class *type* in any way. Only fields, methods, and `extends` clause do.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but I did implemented that interface myself. Does that change anything? After Alex's answer, I planned on deleting it. Does keeping it and implementing it provide additional type safety?

Comment: @DanielKaplan you may delete it as it's been replaced by `Foo` type itself

Answer (score 0):

I guess this counts as an answer, but I'm hoping there is a better one out there. If you implement `reset` like this, the errors go away ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoa1jwHYQBcAnAV2APiIAoBKFDLLAeQCMArAU3IDoATDgGYBLXBwAKReAAcORAkI4QqBABZCIAGnqZGWMAC5tu3QDcwIEh0MByMNY0NjAXwfpHulobQ7j0MxatoaxZ7d0YXDDCsXC8oxgB3IiECMBYQQOJLV18sf0tDAAZs52KsJxoAbkcnSJ0iRQ4CWiNGSAhZAgR4AEEpIWU1CEroAHoR6FV1aGEAD0UJlQ5oWUkiCFrdSYhuMGgAXiC7Kp8F9W4WfaCQ483B7lxLgpvoGvRXjBECWQEwYCWu3pCFoGaCEJK4ADmxU8oOIIihjhi0FwJAAtixZK53ugBCRcOQhHhoG0OgC%20lQRFISARDGBcABPGi0qAdGCU6nQKZkoHeLBjTm4L6Cwm4cwgenTMAAaw4GCcQA)):

```
  reset() {
    assertFooApi(this); // this fixes the errors

    this.a = 'a';
    this.b = 'b';
    this.n = 0;
  }
```

Ideally, I wouldn't have to put that at the top of every internal function.